# Limiting the rows in a datalist

Tags: asp.net, datalist

I have a DataList and binding it to a DataTable.

I want set RowReapeat for it, that limiting rows .

My DataTable have multy row. I want set 3 row for DataList.

I count rows of DataTable then set ColumnRepeat to (Rows of DataTable/3)....

Is there any other way to limiting rows in a DataList??

Comment: Can you give more details? What did you try already? What did you expect to happen, and what actually happened?

Comment: are you trying to implement something like "show more" functionality??

Comment: Yes, for example: i want show 16 of rows in datalist with 3 row and then click "More" show 32 of rows in datalist with 3 row.

Answer (score 0):

you can limit it from SQL query i.e

```
select Top 3 Id  from table;
```

if you'd like to make paging in datalist please refer to this link [Datalist Paging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315575/datalist-paging/7315633#7315633)

Comment: Thanks, but i don't limit it .